pdf-lib actual pdf and pdf viewer from vscode is different
async function testing(data) {
  try {
    // read pdf
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(await readFile("./testing.pdf"));
    const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
    // name
    form.getTextField("name").setText(`${data.field2} ${data.field1}`);

    // modify pdf
    const savedPDF = await pdfDoc.save();

    // write pdf

    const firstFileCheck = await firstFile();

    if (firstFileCheck === false) {
      await writeFile(`./print/print.pdf`, savedPDF);
    } else {
      await addingPage(savedPDF);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

I have this code that works fine? The thing is that when I check the pdf file on VSCode, everything is perfect order with the correct name.
However, if I open the PDF on my computer, all the document has the first' person name. I do not know what the hack is going on?
Why does it have a different text on the same file?
This is the console long ----
hello
John Doe  <---- name
(node:60832) [DEP0044] DeprecationWarning: The `util.isArray` API is deprecated. Please use `Array.isArray()` instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jack H <---- correct name


What is form and where it's used? Because it's not defined anywhere in scope of this function

Sorry, I forgot to add that. But, I've noticed that I am getting DeprecationWarning: The util.isArray API is deprecated. Please use Array.isArray() instead. (Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created) error. Maybe this could be the reason? I am using v22.4.1

Maybe it's reader issue?

hmm, only VScode shows correct way. I'd tried different computers and browsers. It all have a wrong name (except the first one). I also tried to print from VScode driectly but not printing a stuff so im stuck haha
